# Buckets to store words in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to sort an `ArrayList` of strings by first name, each "bucket" stores words that start with the same letter.

This is what I have so far.

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList> bucketMaker(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(26);
    ArrayList<String> bucket = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : list) {
        for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
            if (s.startsWith(String.valueOf(letter))) {
                bucket.add(s);
                output.add(bucket);
                bucket.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

The problem I am having is differentiating between buckets, if I have `bucket.clear();` it simply clears the whole list. How would I make it so that the word stays in bucket, I understand that the `ArrayList` stores references to an object and I do not know how to make it stay in the list without making 26 `ArrayList`'s.  If I leave out `bucket.clear();` then I have the same object in each "bucket".

**EDIT**

I now have

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList> bucketMaker(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(26);
    ArrayList<String> bucket = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        output.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    for (String s : list) {
        for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
            if (s.startsWith(String.valueOf(letter))) {
                output.get(letter-97).add(s);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

which works, thanks for the help!

Comment: You need 26 buckets, but you have one. Which you keep flushing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> output = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

//Add 26 buckets
for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
    output.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}

//add each string to the correct bucket
for (String s : list) {
    for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        if (s.startsWith(String.valueOf(letter))) {

            output.get(letter).add(s);
            //   Get the bucket    add the string
        }
    }
}
```

Remember the `ArrayList` constructor does not create 26 elements, just allocates space for it, atleast as far as you are concerned.

Comment: @MrGreenAcid Note that this solution creates 26 ArrayLists, which you seem to want to avoid. KarthikT does this intelligently by keeping all of these ArrayLists inside of another ArrayList. That way there is only one variable, not 26, and a for loop to create the lists.